# C# Apis to facilitate auto update of application

Tags: c#

I have a C# app in which I need to have an automatic update feature.

Are there any APIs in .Net that would facilitate this process ?

Microsoft clickonce does not let us install the app in the program files, so its not useful for us in our particular case.

Any help.

Thanks,

Comment: https://github.com/github/Shimmer

Answer (score 1):

Here is an solution "Adding automatic updates to your program"
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19623/Adding-automatic-updates-to-your-program-Part-1
And here: [Auto update .NET applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819647/auto-update-net-applications)

Comment: its essentially doing same thing as click-once. I mentioned the reason for not using click-once

Answer (score 0):

InstallShield(http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield.htm), Wise Installer(now Installaware http://www.installaware.com/), and Wix (http://wixtoolset.org/, open source) are most popular.