# System.BadImageFormatException when getting the AssemblyVersion

Tags: c#

So Im trying to implement a auto-updater for my application, [from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/819713/4784140).

I've uploaded my setup file to my server and when Im trying to get the AssemblyVersion of the file I get System.BadImageFormatException, more exactly:

```
System.BadImageFormatException occurred
  HResult=0x8007000B
  Message=Det går inte att läsa in filen eller sammansättningen Setup1.msi eller ett av dess beroenden. Ett försök att läsa in ett program med ogiltigt format gjordes.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Reflection.AssemblyName.nGetFileInformation(String s)
   at System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(String assemblyFile)
   at WindowsFormsApp1.Form1..ctor() in C:\Users\Gustav\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Form1.cs:line 50
   at WindowsFormsApp1.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Gustav\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Program.cs:line 22

Inner Exception 1:
BadImageFormatException: Det går inte att läsa in filen eller sammansättningen Setup1.msi eller ett av dess beroenden. Ett försök att läsa in ett program med ogiltigt format gjordes.
```

I've read that this is because of an x64 application trying to run a x86 DLL, but this shouldn't be the case since it's the exact same application im trying to get the info from?

```
    string remoteUri = "http://<URL>/downloads/";
    string fileName = "Setup1.msi", myStringWebResource = null;
    // Create a new WebClient instance.
    WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
    // Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
    myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
        myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, fileName);

        if (AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("Setup1.msi").Version > Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version)
        {
            logger.Add("Update found!");
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = "Setup1.msi";
            Process.Start(startInfo);
            this.Close();
        }
```

My setup is x86 and the application is also x86.

Comment: .msi is not a .NET file, why would you check it with `AssemblyVersion`?

Comment: Wow im stupid, so it's not possible to do this with a .msi file?

Comment: How about [using `FileVersionInfo`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1537764/107625)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scratch my old answer, it seems that there is no easy way to set the file version for MSI packages. The solution then, which is a bit more work and requires an external dependency is to actually query the MSI file property table.

For this code to work (it does, I've checked it against a proper MSI file) you'll need the assemblies `Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll` and `Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Linq.dll` from the [WiX Toolset SDK](http://wixtoolset.org). You can find the files in the zipped version of [their releases](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/releases) or in the installation folder if you install the whole toolset.

```
using(var database = new QDatabase("node-v6.10.3-x64.msi", DatabaseOpenMode.ReadOnly)) {
    var productVersion = database.Properties.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Property == "ProductVersion");

    if(productVersion != null)
        Console.WriteLine($"Product version is {productVersion.Value}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, though every field is blank when I do this on my MSI file,

Comment: Yeah it seems that getting a real FileVersion property on the binary was really hard so I've updated my answer with another method which reads the properties from the msi manifest instead.